# How can I trigger a function inside 'methode' from external javascript in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js

How can I trigger a function inside 'methode' from external javascript in Vue js ?

I want to trigger call() inside methodes from index.html in vue js

Can anyone help me sort out this ?

Comment: <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
     
        <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
        <script>
    
          $(document).ready(function(){
           // need to call function call() here from vue js methode
          });
        </script>
      </body>

Answer (score 0):

You could have your external javascript set a global variable, and then within your Vue component watch for changes on that global variable, and let that trigger the method call. That might not work reliably though because the global variable might already have been set before vue gets mounted.

Is there more going on in your document.ready than you've shown here? Your  Vue component's Mounted hook could possibly serve just as well?

Comment: Thanks for your time
very sorry to ask again
How can we watch global variable in Vue
I am new in Vue
Thanks

Comment: You should probably be firing your Vue method from within the Vue 'mounted' hook then.

 Vue has various life cycle hooks, you can read about the 'mounted hook' here:

https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

and as that says, If you need to be sure other parts of the page have also loaded, use $nextTick as well.